# why does webgl blending not support COLOR_LOGIC_OP mode?

Tags: webgl

I am new to WebGL. I create a FBO and render a texture on it. Now another texture is suppose to be rendered in the same coordinate by blending the fragments' R,G,B and A values in COLOR_LOGIC_OP mode. Then I checkout the WebGL Specification, and could not find any information about the blending mode. Has the blending mode not been implemented yet?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is because WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0 and [OpenGL ES 2.0 doesn't support glLogicOp](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/).

It's also [not in OpenGL ES 3.0](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man3/) either which the next version of WebGL will be based on so it will most likely not appear in WebGL for the forceable future.

Comment: What a pity. I mean this feature is used so common in applications,  and now I have to implement it by myself.But the problem is the shading language does not support bitwise operation. Thus I have to read pixels from FBO and do logicOps in my own application. That may cause significant performance loss I think.Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: It's probably best to start a new question and ask specifically what problem you are trying to solve.